# http POST request on shared hosting

Tags: php, json, post, request

I'm trying to do a HTTP POST Request to a SMA Datalogger, that uses JSON-RPC to respond to HTTP requests.

Using *hurl.it* I can make a successful request, for example:

> Destination: POST, http://aaa.no-ip.org:101/rpc, follow redirects:on.
>   Headers: Host: aaa.no-ip.org:101, Content-Type:text/plain.
>   Body: RPC={"proc":"GetPlantOverview","format":"JSON","version":"1.0","id":"1"}

Then *hurl.it* process's the following request:

```
Success
POST http://aaa.no-ip.org:101/rpc
200 OK      401 bytes      3.76 secs 

    HEADERS

    Accept: */*
    Accept-Encoding: application/json
    Content-Length: 122
    Content-Type: text/plain
    Host: aaa.no-ip.org
    User-Agent: runscope/0.1

    BODY

    RPC=%7B%22proc%22%3A%22GetPlantOverview%22%2C%22format%22%3A%22JSON%22%2C%22version%22%3A%221.0%22%2C%22id%22%3A%221%22%7D
```

And the response is:

```
HEADERS

Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, max-age=0
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 401
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Wed, 22 Oct 2014 14:15:50 GMT
Keep-Alive: 300
Pragma: no-cache
Server: Sunny WebBox

BODY

{"format":"JSON","result":{"overview":[{"unit":"W","meta":"GriPwr","name":"GriPwr","value":"99527"},{"unit":"kWh","meta":"GriEgyTdy","name":"GriEgyTdy","value":"842.849"},{"unit":"kWh","meta":"GriEgyTot","name":"GriEgyTot","value":"2851960.438"},{"unit":"","meta":"OpStt","name":"OpStt","value":""},{"unit":"","meta":"Msg","name":"Msg","value":""}]},"proc":"GetPlantOverview","version":"1.0","id":"1"}
```

My problem is, every time I try to replicate these requests I always get:

```
string(0) ""
```

It could be because I'm using a shared host. I tried cURL, plain PHP (socket and file_get_contents, and even jQuery.
Can someone please provide an example on how to do this request?
Either jquery or php, I don't even care anymore, I've been trying for 2 weeks, and so many attempts, and either I get code errors or just `string(0)""`.

PS: for previous attempts examples, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26408153/solar-energy-monitoring-sma-webbox-json-post-request

Answer (score 0):

Here is the JSONRPC Client I have used to successfully make JSON RPC HTTP Requests. Hope this helps:
You may need to change some things to work in your code.

Found here: https://code.google.com/p/pmvc-framework/source/browse/trunk/src/main/php/pmvc/remoting/jsonrpc/JsonRpcClient.class.php?r=328

```
<?php

use Exception;
use ReflectionClass;

/*
 * A client for accessing JSON-RPC over HTTP servers.
 *
 */
class JsonRpcClient
{

  private $_url              = false;
  private $_reuseConnections = true;

  private static $_curl = null;
  private $_nextId = 99;

  /*
   * Creates the client for the given URL.
   * @param string $_url
   */
  public function __construct($url) 
{
    $this->_url = $url;

}
    /*
    * Returns a curl resource.
    * @return resource
    */
    private function getCurl()
    {
        if (!isset(self::$_curl)) {

        // initialize
        self::$_curl = curl_init();

        // set options
        curl_setopt(self::$_curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,      true);
        curl_setopt(self::$_curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,   true);
        curl_setopt(self::$_curl, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE,     $this->_reuseConnections===false);
        curl_setopt(self::$_curl, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT,    $this->_reuseConnections===false);
        curl_setopt(self::$_curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,   5);

        return self::$_curl;
        }
    }

   /*
   * Invokes the given method with the given arguments
   * on the server and returns it's value.  If {@code $returnType}
   * is specified than an instance of the class that it names
   * will be created passing the json object (stdClass) to it's
   * constructor.
   *
   * @param string $method the method to invoke
   * @param Array $params the parameters (if any) to the method
   * @param string $id the request id
   * @param Array $headers any additional headers to add to the request
   */
    public function invoke($method, Array $params=Array(), $id=false, Array $headers=Array())
    {
    // get curl
    $curl = $this->getCurl();

    // set url
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $this->_url);

    // set post body
    $request = json_encode(
        Array(
            'jsonrpc' => '2.0',
            'method'  => $method,
            'params'  => $params,
            'id'      => ($id===false) ? ++$this->nextId : $id
        )
    );

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST,  true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  $request);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,  true);

    // set headers
    $curlHeaders = Array();
    $curlHeaders []= "Content-type: application/json-rpc";
    for (reset($headers); list($key, $value)=each($headers); ) {
    $curlHeaders []= $key.": ".$value."\n";

    }
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $curlHeaders);

    // post the data
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    if (!$response) {
        throw new Exception('cURL error '.curl_error($curl).' while making request to '.$this->_url);

    }

    // decode json response
    $response = json_decode($response);
    if ($response==NULL || curl_error($curl)!=0) {
        throw new Exception("JSON parsing error occured: ".json_last_error());

        // throw errors
        } else if (isset($response->error)) {
            $msg = 'JSON-RPC error';
            if (isset($response->error->message) && !empty($response->error->message)) {
                $msg .= ': "' . $response->error->message . '"';
            }
            $msg .= "\n";
            $msg .= 'URL: ' . $this->_url;
            $msg .= "\n";
            $msg .= 'Method: ' . $method;
            $msg .= "\n";
            $msg .= 'Arguments: ' . self::printArguments($params, 2);

            if (isset($response->error->code)) {
                throw new Exception($msg, intval($response->error->code));
            } else {
                throw new Exception($msg);
            }

        }
        // get the headers returns (APPSVR, JSESSIONID)
        $responsePlusHeaders = Array();
        $responsePlusHeaders['result'] = $response->result;
        $responsePlusHeaders['headers'] = curl_getinfo($curl);
        // return the data
        return $responsePlusHeaders;
    }

    /*
    * Printing arguments.
    * @param $arg
    * @param $depth
    */
    private static function printArguments($args, $depth=1)
    {
        $argStrings = Array();
        foreach ($args as $arg) {
        $argStrings[] = self::printArgument($arg, $depth);
        }
        return implode($argStrings, ', ');
    }

    /*
    * Print an argument.
    * @param $arg
    * @param $depth
    */
    private static function printArgument($arg, $depth=1)
    {
        if ($arg === NULL) {
        return 'NULL';

        } else if (is_array($arg)) {
            if ($depth > 1) {
                return '[' . self::printArguments($arg, ($depth - 1)) . ']';
            } else {
                return 'Array';
            }
        } else if (is_object($arg)) {
            return 'Object';
        } else if (is_bool($arg)) {
            return ($arg === TRUE) ? 'true' : 'false';
        } else if (is_string($arg)) {
            return "'$arg'";
        }
        return strval($arg);
    }
}
```

Usage would then be:

```
include JsonRpcClient.php


$client = new JsonRpcClient('http://aaa.no-ip.org:101/rpc');
$response = $client->invoke('GetPlantOverview', 1, array('Host: aaa.no-ip.org:101'));
```